# If a variable does not exist is it bound?

Tags: predicate-logic

I've been doing Logic equivalences questions and I've been taught that a variable $x$ is bound if it is under any quantifier such as $ \exists $ or $ \forall$ however I've come across a question where in the answer it states that a variable is bound even though no quantifier exists to bound it:

$ \forall y [\exists x P(x,y) \Rightarrow \neg S(y)] $

$ \forall y \forall x [P(x,y) \Rightarrow \neg S(y)] $ by equivalence 37: note that $x$ is not free in $S(y)$.

Equivalence 37 in my notes states

Note: If $x$ does not occur free in $B$

$ \forall x (A\Rightarrow B) $ eqv $ \exists x A \Rightarrow B $

$ \exists x (A \Rightarrow B) $ eqv $ \forall x A \Rightarrow B $

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here? Can someone please explain what it means?

Comment: The equivalence between the two first formulae holds because $x$ is not free in $S(y)$. In general (consider the last two formulae) we have that $x$ does not occur free in $B$ if : either (i) $x$ does not occur at all into $B$, or (ii) $x$ occurs only bound into $B$, i.e. $B$ is like : $\forall x C(x)$.

Comment: Regarding the question in the title : "If a variable does not exist is it bound?", the answer is : **NO**. But the restriction is : $x$ is not free in $S(y)$" and if the variable $x$ does not occur at all in $S(y)$, it is not free in it.

Comment: Doesn't bound mean "not free"?

Comment: YES... but "not free" means either (i) bound, or (ii) not occurring at all.

Comment: Ok i got it now , thank you.